# What verb should I use for this "mod" operation, e.g. $21=5z+7y\implies1\equiv2y\pmod 5$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, terminology

What verb should I use for this operation below?
$$21=5z+7y\implies1\equiv2y\pmod 5$$

Can I just say "mod 5" on both sides? After all "mod" as a math term is not included in an English dictionary, so I am really not sure how to use it in a sentence. And please provide other ways to describe this if possible.

Comment: "reduce *modulo* $5$"

Comment: Can you use it in a sentence? @Blue

Comment: "Given $21=5z+7y$, we can reduce *modulo* $5$ to obtain $1\equiv 2y$." ...  "The relation $21=5z+7y$, reduced *modulo* $5$, yields $1\equiv 2y$." ... Etc.

Comment: @Blue Apparently your comment is the best answer so far. If you expand it into one I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the conventional way to read the operation is "reduce *modulo* $5$"; for instance,

- "Given $21=5z+7y$, we can reduce *modulo* $5$ to obtain $1\equiv 2y$."
- "The relation $21=5z+7y$, reduced *modulo* $5$, yields $1\equiv 2y$."

*Informally*, you could say "modding by $5$", which is about on the order of saying "square-rooting". You wouldn't want to put this in a scholarly paper, but a lecture audience would understand you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine as it stands (that is, when you display the entire implication in a single line). Then it makes the $\pmod 5$ cover the entire expression. The meaning would then be clear.

Comment: Actually I am asking how to read that line out loud to others. For example, if I read $f(x)=x\implies f'(x)=1$ to someone it would be "differentiate $f(x)$ equals $x$ on both sides to obtain $f$ prime equals $1$".

Comment: @trisct I had no idea. But then you could still read it directly: *Reducing the equation $21=5z+7y$ modulo $5$ gives $1=2y,* or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

twenty-one being of form five times x plus seven times y, implies that, 1 is the remainder on division by five  of two times y .

Google states:

mod2
/mäd/
preposition MATHEMATICS
preposition: mod
another term for modulo.